# Custom right click menu Excel Add-in not loading

Tags: excel, vba, excel-addins

I've used the [Ron de Bruin tutorial](https://www.rondebruin.nl/win/s6/win001.htm) to create a custom right click menu.
This works no problem when using it in an XLSM file type, but when I try to turn this into an Excel Add-in, the right click menu doesn't appear. Is there something specific I need to add in to the code to enable it?

The code I used in 'ThisWorkbook' is:

```
Private Sub Workbook_Activate()
Call AddToCellMenu
End Sub

Private Sub Workbook_Deactivate()
Call DeleteFromCellMenu
End Sub
```

The code I used in a separate module is:

```
Sub AddToCellMenu()
Dim ContextMenu As CommandBar
Dim MySubMenu As CommandBarControl

Call DeleteFromCellMenu

Set ContextMenu = Application.CommandBars("Cell")

Set MySubMenu = ContextMenu.Controls.Add(Type:=msoControlPopup, before:=3)

With MySubMenu
    .Caption = "Recruitment"
    .Tag = "My_Cell_Control_Tag"

    With .Controls.Add(Type:=msoControlButton)
        .OnAction = "'" & ThisWorkbook.Name & "'!" & "Rejections"
        .FaceId = 97
        .Caption = "Format Rejections"
    End With
    With .Controls.Add(Type:=msoControlButton)
        .OnAction = "'" & ThisWorkbook.Name & "'!" & "Hires"
        .FaceId = 87
        .Caption = "Format Hires"
    End With

End With

ContextMenu.Controls(4).BeginGroup = True
End Sub



Sub DeleteFromCellMenu()
Dim ContextMenu As CommandBar
Dim ctrl As CommandBarControl

Set ContextMenu = Application.CommandBars("Cell")

For Each ctrl In ContextMenu.Controls
    If ctrl.Tag = "My_Cell_Control_Tag" Then
        ctrl.Delete
    End If
Next ctrl

On Error Resume Next
ContextMenu.FindControl(ID:=3).Delete
On Error GoTo 0
End Sub
```

Rejections and Hires are the two macros I'm asking for it to call. These are simple macros that I know work ok so didn't bother adding the code for those.

Comment: Please [edit] your question and show **exactly** the code **you** use in your project (alternatively add a [mcve]). Links to similar code are not sufficient we need to see *your* code (links might break in future and the question becomes useless to other readers). Also note that *"it won't work"* is no useful error description. Tell us which error you get and in which line or what your code actually does vs. what you expect it to do.

Comment: If you're using an add-in, you probably want the `Workbook_Open` and `Workbook_BeforeClose` events rather than the Activate/Deactivate ones.

Comment: @Rory that seems to have done the trick. The Workbook_BeforeClose command didn't work so I reverted to using deactivate.
Thank you.